# How to change new subscriber pop-up message?

Tags: magento2, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

[image]

How do I change this popup text after a customer puts in their email to subscribe to the newsletter?

I have looked in the NewAction.php and its not there.

I am using magento version 2.3.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just run the grep command in the SSH terminal to find message comes from which file

```
grep -rnw app/ -e 'if you do not find this in your inbox'
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced. I use filezilla and I'm not sure how to run a grep command with the SSH terminal? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you know hoy to cache using command?

Comment: Nope, I'm very new to all this

Comment: if you have SSH detail and you know how to run command than grep command helpfull to you to find out message comes from which file
can you give me site URL, so that i can check which action call and i help you

Comment: https://www.brightlife.com.au/

Comment: you need to connet SSH, and run grep command to find out message comes from which file

Comment: I connected through SSH!

Comment: grep -rnw app/ -e 'if you do not find this in your inbox' output: app/: No such file or directory

Comment: please run this command in root directory, currently you are not at root directory of your magento

Comment: run ls command to list all the directory, if it show app folder than you are at correct directory

Comment: i typed in run and it says command not found. How do i get to root directory?

Comment: i typed in cd / then typed in the grep and it still says no such file or directory

Comment: please run command     ls

Comment: list of directory is show, if you see the directory like app,pub,vendor,car than its a root directory than you can run grep command

Comment: did you find the directory?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I only work here 2 days a week. When I type ls it shows: backup, bash_logout,bashrc,websitee name,gitconfig,gnupg, local, ssh

Comment: enable template path hint from enable than you can get root  path of your website  https://meetanshi.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2/